# Why didn't Kira kill manipulate the mafia to kill Mello?

Tags: death-note

In the Mafia Arc, Kira was able to get hold of the names of the Mafia members under Mello's command, but the only thing he did was kill them. Couldn't he have manipulated them to help out in the assualt/kill Mello themselves?

Seems like a plot hole to me.

The same could be said for Mello killing the majority of the SPK members - he could have manipulated them to kill Near. However, this could be forgiven because he might have wanted to 'fight' Near 'mentally' with defeating Kira, the last boss.

Is there a rule that prevents them from manipulating to kill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a rule indicating that someone's death must not cause another's:

> Whether the cause of the individual’s death is either a suicide or
>   accident. If the death leads to the death of more than the intended,
>   the person will simply die of a heart attack. This is to ensure that
>   other lives are not influenced.

From http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note

Comment: Okay, then that explains it. Still, Kira could have probably manipulated the mafia members to handcuff the other members or something though, just to help out with the assault. But that's petty... :D

Comment: Oh wait, it says, "lead to the death of more than the intended." So I guess that takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly Mello and Near didn't reveal their real names to their groups and you couldn't use "Kill Near/Mello before dying of a heart attack" otherwise Light would have been able to kill L much sooner by controlling someone in the taskforce

Comment: Couldn't "Kill the person you know as 'Mello'" have worked? Or something like "Kill the Leader of your Mafia Group?"(Assuming Light assumes Mello is the leader). Also, I don't think Light could have been able to control someone in the taskforce, because L arranged it so that if he was to die, Light would take the blame (and Light knew this, so he didn't kill him).

Comment: @Secret your point with L would be correct, L did say to Light that if anything was to happen to him the Taskforce was instructed to assume Light was Kira

Comment: @Secret with the first 2 examples you provided i think the abstraction would have failed, the Death Note seems to have been designed to be accurate without any misinterpretation, however Omega has got the right answer, i never really had time to fully read the "How to use" at the breaks of the episodes

Comment: I guess you're right about Death Note being very accurate, so yeah that abstraction would have probably failed.